# About Symbol.iterator and iterators, iterables

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable

On this page:

https://javascript.info/iterable

They explain how an iterator works by constructing an iterator from scratch:

```js
let range = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    this.current = this.from;
    return this;
  },

  next() {
    if (this.current <= this.to) {
      return { done: false, value: this.current++ };
    } else {
      return { done: true };
    }
  }
};

for (let num of range) {
  alert(num); // 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

Basically, an iterator must return an object like this: { done: boolean, value: current value }

Then it's put to work using a for...of loop:

```js
for (let num of range) {
  alert(num); // 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

So we know that for...of calls the iterator and its next function. We just know it works. But then they explain how we can call them explicitly, with this code:

```js
let str = "Hello";

// does the same as
// for (let char of str) alert(char);

let iterator = str[Symbol.iterator]();

while (true) {
  let result = iterator.next();
  if (result.done) break;
  alert(result.value); // outputs characters one by one
}
```

But they are calling the default iterator. They aren't calling the iterator they made from scratch. I assume it's not possible with the one they created from scratch because of how return works. So does for...of have a special functionality that can't be recreated? Like it knows to remember what value you are at and continue from there and doesn't exit at return.

This is just to help my understanding. I always like when they explain how to recreate existing functionality and wanted to know if this could be fully re-created without using the default iterator.

Comment: What? They aren't calling the iterator they made because you already know it has e.g. a next method. They're showing how to access it on *something else*.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what it is you're asking here. `for ... of` examines the iterated value objects and checks the `done` flag for you, as well as grabbing the `value`. You can create a function that exercises that too.

Comment: Your last example will also work if you do `let iterator = range[Symbol.iterator]();`. So there will be no problem on that, it was just a different example.

Comment: Why does this not work:

`while (true) {
  let result = range[Symbol.iterator]().next();
  if (result.done) break;
  alert(result.value);`
}

Comment: Because you're creating a new iterator each time? So it always starts over.

Comment: @SRCP You must not call `range[Symbol.iterator]()` repeatedly, only the `next()` method. The `[Symbol.iterator]` method of `range` re-initialises `current` on every call.